# How can you get a transition to a new view similar to how an App is opened in SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, view, swiftui, transition

So when you open an app on your iPhone it transitions from your AppIcon into a view that looks completely different in a way that feels natural. I try to simulate the animation in the GIF image below. How would you achieve this effect in SwiftUI?

[image]

*You might need to refresh to see the animation.*

I will enhance this question with some sample code on how far I've got tonight, but perhaps someone else has a demo sooner. That would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a feeling on how animations work in SwiftUI and how to combine them, I made this little animation for you which consists of two parts:

```
struct SplashScreen: View {

@State private var circleAlpha = 1.0
@State private var sizeCircle: CGFloat = 0
@State private var textAlpha = 1.0

func handleAnimations() {
    runAnimationPart1()
    let deadline: DispatchTime = .now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
        self.runAnimationPart2()
    }
}

func runAnimationPart1() {
    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1)) {
        textAlpha = 0
    }
}

func runAnimationPart2() {
    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1)) {
        sizeCircle = 1400
    }
}

var body: some View {

    ZStack {

        Text("Your App Icon")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
            .opacity(textAlpha)

        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: sizeCircle, height: sizeCircle,
                   alignment: .leading)
            .opacity(circleAlpha)

    }
    .onAppear() {
        self.handleAnimations()
    }
} }
```